# Casting back to derived class from base class using Reflections

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

Here what I am trying to do:

```
BaseClass base = (BaseClass)
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstance("DerivedClassDLL","DerivedClass");
```

However, there is a property I need to reach from DerivedClass to display, etc. BaseClass doesn't have that property and I cannot make it happen.

So somehow I need to cast it back to DerivedClass to reach it BUT DerivedClass isn't referenced so I cannot reach it is type easily unlike BaseClass which has reference so I can use it.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you can use Convert.ChangeType

Comment: Have you tried simply casting it?

Comment: @JotaBe: I cannot since I don't know the type of `DerivedClass` as I only have `BaseClass` that doesn't have the property I want.

Comment: Do you know the name and type of the property or do you get it dynamically?

Comment: @JotaBe: Even though I know it still it may come arbitrary from a `DropDownList` so that's why I have `BaseClass` so `DerivedClass` could by anything which implements `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have two options in this case:

- use dynamic
- use reflection

#### Using dynamic

```
BaseClass foo = (BaseClass) AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                     .CreateInstance("DerivedClassDLL","DerivedClass");
dynamic derived = foo;
string someProperty = derived.SomeProperty;
```

#### Using reflection

```
string someProperty = (string)foo.GetType()
                                 .GetProperty("SomeProperty")
                                 .GetValue(foo, null);
```

Comment: So in this case, `foo` happens to be `BaseClass` which doesn't have the property I need. Do you think it still works as casting happens?

Comment: only the object reference is typed as `BaseClass`, the object instance that is referenced is still of the derived class so reflection/dynamic should still work

Comment: Also you probably meant `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` and not `CreateInstance` in your initial call, right?

Comment: Similar, returning `ObjectHandle` instance which calls `Unwrap()` method later on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an instance of the derived class, this bit of reflection should do it:

```
var myPropertyInfo = typeof(instanceOfDerivedClass).GetProperty("DerivedClassProperty");
var myPropertyValue = myPropertyInfo.GetValue(instanceOfDerivedClass) as [property type];
```

Comment: Actually even though I have instance of it, I don't know which type is that other than its BaseClass. So I can use `object` type other than `BaseClass` type to assign the instance.