# Can you add a Derived Class to a list of its base class then call a method of the Derived class from the list of base class in C#

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

Can you add a Derived Class to a list of its base class then call a method of the Derived class from the list of base class(possibly by casting it back to the Derived class since you know it was originally a Derived class)

```
public class MySystem
{
    public string name;

    MySystem(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //dostuff
    }
}

public class PowerSystem : MySystem
{
    public int totalPower;

    PowerSystem (string name, int power) : base(name)
    {
        this.totalPower = power;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        //Do other stuff
    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<MySystem> SystemList = new List<MySystem>();

    SystemList.Add(new System("Shields"));
    SystemList.Add(new System("Hull"));

    Power p = new Power("Power", 10);
    SystemList.Add(p);

    foreach(MainSystems ms in SystemList)   
    {
        if(ms.name != "Power")
            ms.Update();
        else
            (PowerSystem)ms.Update();   //This doesn't work
    }

}
```

So what I'm trying to do is run the update method for every element in the list, with the exeption of the one I named power and instead run the Power.Update method.

The closest post I have found to answering this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951709/casting-back-to-derived-class-from-base-class-using-reflections) unfortunately I don't fully understand it.

I'm hoping that the list is holding a reference to PowerSystem p and that somehow I can convert it and access the PowerSystem menthod.

I hope this is clear.
Thanks

PS if you have a better idea for this I'm all ears.

Comment: Code snippets should only be used for client-side code: HTML, JavaScript and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) - mark `Update` in base class `virtual` and `override` it in derived class.

> Base classes may define and implement virtual methods, and derived
>   classes can override them, which means they provide their own
>   definition and implementation. At run-time, when client code calls the
>   method, the CLR looks up the run-time type of the object, and invokes
>   that override of the virtual method. Thus in your source code you can
>   call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's version of
>   the method to be executed.

```
public class MySystem
{
    public string name;

    MySystem(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        //dostuff
    }
}

public class PowerSystem : MySystem
{
    public int totalPower;

    PowerSystem (string name, int power) : base(name)
    {
        this.totalPower = power;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        //Do other stuff
    }
}
```

Now, `PowerSystem.Update()` will get called automatically

```
foreach(MainSystems ms in SystemList)   
{
    ms.Update();
}
```

For `MySystem` instances it will call `MySystem.Update`, but for `PowerSystem` instances the override will be called.

Comment: Even though its being called from a list of the base clase MySystem?

Comment: Marking the method virtual will cause that happen even though during compile time your variable is types to be `MySystem` - at runtime top-most `Update` override will get called.

Comment: @user2462076: Yes, that's the main use of `virtual`.

Comment: I love it thanks, Now I have a second question, maybe I should make another post. But its so related I figured I would put it here and move it if you say to. If I changed PowerSystem. Update to require something to be passed to it, such as Update(int power) can I still force it to be called via virtual and override or would I have to define a virtual Update(int power) in MySystem too?

Comment: Overrided method signature must stay the same - have the same set of parameters and return the same type.

Comment: @user2462076: `virtual` only works if all the overrides have the same signature.  So to add an argument to one derived class, it would have to be added to all, including the base class.

Comment: One more question popped into my head, I'll go start reading in a bit, but I'm excited and don't want to wait lol, is it possible to use something like this to access the parameters that I have in PowerSystem from the list of MySystem? aka to access totalPower from the list?

Comment: Not without type checking and casting to `PowerSystem` (which is pretty much what you were doing before): `var powerSystem = ms as PowerSystem; if(powerSystem != null) { /* you can use powerSystem here */ } else { /* it was not PowerSystem instance */ }`

Comment: Man,  MarcinJuraszek, you get better and better the more I read this post, After you helped me last night I implemented the changes in my code then started googling polymorphism, I came back to just to check it and noticed that you actually included a link for me about polymorphism, if I could uprate your answer a second time I would!